# c# application - popup a form everytime user login in windows useraccount

Tags: c#

good day guys, Can anyone help me with my c# application. My application would pop up everytime a user login in windows useraccount
I have this code. but my problem is everytime I login there's another form1 will popup. And if i login 2 times... there will be multiple form1. 
I want it to be only one form1. hide and popup again only one (form1)

Thanks

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += OnSessionSwitch;

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

        this.Focus();
        this.BringToFront();
        this.TopMost = true;
    }


static void OnSessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
     {

        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon:
                // User has logged on to the computer.

                break;

            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogoff:
                // User has logged off from the computer.
                break;

            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:

                Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
                frm1.Show();

                break;

            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                // The computer has been locked.
                break;
        }


    }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.Hide();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

    }
```

Comment: lol, just hide/show the active form. Don't create new ones all the time.

Comment: I am not sure if the method has to be static, but if not, remove it. Remove the `new Form1` stuff and just use `this.Hide()` and `this.Show()`

Comment: it wont work, try it already. multiple form1 everytime i login.

Comment: Can't believe that... use this: https://ideone.com/jKzjLs

Comment: yeah, it wont multiply another form1 but form1 did not popup everytime i login. I just to click it in the taskbar. I want it to popup again. thank you, appreciate it.

Comment: When you click the button it `hides` and `minimizes` the window. Maybe you should minimize it. Or normalize it again in the event.

Comment: I maximize it in the event. It Work. Thank you.

Comment: Added it as an answer. No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `static` method. Check my example below. You also forgot to `Maximize` the form when you show it in the event.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += OnSessionSwitch;

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

        this.Focus();
        this.BringToFront();
        this.TopMost = true;
    }


void OnSessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
     {

        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogon:
                // User has logged on to the computer.

                break;

            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLogoff:
                // User has logged off from the computer.
                break;

            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                this.Show();

                break;

            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                // The computer has been locked.
                break;
     }


 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.Hide();
     this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

 }
```

Comment: I forgot about it. Thank you so much.